# Change html tag when text is wrapped

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Is that possible to tell your HTML to display (B) when finding the text in (A) is wrapped? If not wrapped, still display (A)

(A)

```
    <div>
     <span>abcdefgabcdefgabcdefg</span>
     <span>abcdefgabcdefgabcdefg</span>
    </div>
```

(B)

```
    <div>
     <img src="a.jpeg"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: Take a look at [getClientRects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects), a wrapped inline element contains more than one DOMRect object in the list.

Comment: well show us what you have tried first. And then maybe someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One thought -- using jQuery, you can calculate the difference between the `innerWidth` of the containing element and the `scrollWidth`, as long as you set `white-space: nowrap` in your CSS.

Then, if the scroll width is wider than the width of the containing element, this would mean the content (e.g., text) in it would wrap, and you could display your alternate content instead.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#test")[0].scrollWidth > $("#test").innerWidth()) {
    // text will wrap, display alternate content
    console.log("text will wrap");
  }
});
```

```css
#test {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"> <span>fgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg</span>
</div>
```